# Programatically load default billing and shipping address

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, customer-address, billing-address

Magento 2 programatically load default billing and shipping address..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an example of getting default customer's billing and shipping address if you have the customerId and using the customerRepository `Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` and the addressRepository `Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface`

```
 $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
 $billingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
 $shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();

//get default billing address
 try {
    $billingAddress = $this->addressRepository->getById($billingAddressId);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    //
}
```

Comment: the above code returns only the address id .can you help me to load the address by address id..?

Comment: Answer is updated!

Comment: this should be added to block or controller?

Comment: _getAddressHtml($billingAddress ) will foramt the  address?