# Load default address when logged in on magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, customer-address

I want to load magento2.1 default address on my cart page address box when i'm logged in.

mean that, when i'm in one step checkout page and logged in, in my address part, see default address instead of please select your address...

Comment: Check this answer, it should be what you need https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/187779/76597

Comment: can you please elaborate your question little more?

Comment: Updated question